# wrong use of background-image:url

Tags: html, image, css, url

I have a litle question related to css´s background-image:url()-tag

I have this:

```
<div id="container">
</div>
```

in css:

```
#container{
    background-image:url('path/to/image'); 
    width: 1000px;
    padding: 25px;
    margin: 100px auto 0 auto;
    min-height: 300px;
    border:1px solid blue;
}
```

The image is:
height:1500px and width: 3400px.

As a result I get the upper-left corner of the image displayed in my "container"(rest of image is missing),I just wanted the image to be resized in this container so it should be width: 1000px and height: 300px, you know why I have this bug?

Comment: you're really modifying the size of your container. Instead of using background-image, use an img tag, and modify the css specific to that element. <img src='path/to/image' style='height: 1500px; width: 3400px;' />

Answer (score 1):

This might solve your problem (insert into #container CSS):

```
    background-size: 100%;
```

Comment: or background-size: cover;